# Images not rendering on server

Tags: html, ftp

I am uploading a web page to ftp server. This page contains images with relative paths. All my images are contained in a folder called Images. A image source tag looks like this.

```
<img src="./images/construction_right.png" width="118" height="118" alt="under construction">
```

The problem is that the images are not rendering when i browse the page on the server. But when i create an ankor on the html page and click it i can navigate to the image.

Please advise.

Thank you for your time.

**Edit:**

FTP server:

07/16/2011 02:10PM      Directory .
07/16/2011 02:10PM      Directory ..
07/16/2011 02:08PM      Directory images
07/16/2011 02:10PM            929 index.html

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>KDC SARL</title>
</head>

<body>
<div align="center"  style="border:double;background-color:#933">
    <table>
        <tr>
          <td><img src="images/construction_left.png" width="118" height="118" alt="under construction"></td>
          <td>
            <div>
                <div align="center">
                    <strong style="font-size:36px">KDC furniture website is under construction</strong>
            </div> 
          </td>
          <td><img src="images/construction_right.png" width="118" height="118" alt="under construction"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>     
<br/>
    <img src="images/girl_sofa.jpg" width="882" height="262" alt="girl saloon">
    <br/>
    <img src="images/kinwai.jpg" width="883" height="290" alt="saloon">
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: where is the page, relative to the images?  You can try removing the ./ and just do "images/construction_right.png".  You can also check to ensure that your page doesn't have an HTML BASE tag that could potentially affect the relative paths.

Comment: @mikey i removed ./ and it doesn't work. There is no HTML BASE tag. When i create an ankor tag and supply the same src of the image, i can navigate and view it.

Comment: Do you mean <a href="./Images/construction_right.png">test</a> works when you click it, but the img tag does not?

Comment: @mikey here is the ankor tag: <a href="./Images/construction_right.png">go</a>. when i click it i am redirected and i can view the image within the browser.

Comment: have you tried "../Images" if not paste your code something could be disabling the view of your images or your server might not be allowing access seems like a bizzare issue.

Comment: @Moussa - is it "Images" or "images" directory (ie capitalised first letter or not?) This may be causing your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Remove the ./ - that's superfluous
- Check the case of the folder. That may be causing a weird error.

Comment: i have tried that also, it doesn't work. I have edited my question please check it.

Comment: Does any other website work on the server? It may be the mime/type or such that Apache is serving weirdly.